# strange syntax in javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax, mootools

I'm working on debugging some code someone else wrote (using Mootools as the base library), and I came across this function:

```
[note, $H(options.text).getKeys()].flatten().each(function(option){
  // bunch of stuff happening
});
```

I've never seen this syntax before, with the brackets and the $H notation (eg. `[note, $H(options.text).getKeys()]`). Can anyone explain how that works or point me to a reference on it?

Thanks!

Comment: `[]` are an Array literal. `$H()` is calling a function named `$H`. No different than `var myarray = []; myarray[0] = 'some val'; myarray[1] = some_func('some arg').some_other_func();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This basically aggregates two arrays together.  Take, for example, this code:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [4,5,6];
var c = [a, b].flatten();
alert(c);
```

The arrays `[1,2,3]` and `[4,5,6]` are combined (or "flattened") into a single array, `1,2,3,4,5,6`.

In your code:

```
[note, $H(options.text).getKeys()].flatten()
```

`note` (perhaps another array) and whatever `getKeys()` returns are flattened into a single array.  Then, a function is performed across each element.

**Update:**

The [$H function](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Types/Hash#H) is a utility function in [Mootools](http://mootools.net/) that is a shortcut for Hash().

Comment: thanks for the explanation. It seems obvious now. I think coming from a more PHP background that `$H` really threw me off. I don't recall ever seeing that in JS. Is there a reason to use that rather than just the function name?

Comment: I don't really know Mootools that well, but `$` is a perfectly valid name for a function in Javascript.  jQuery uses it for its main selector function.  I'm not sure what the `$H` function is or what defined it (it almost looks like minified or crunched code?) - Maybe some Mootools people can chime in.

Comment: @Mike-- I added some more info in the original post with the only other usage of `$H` in the script.

Comment: I looked it up.  `$H` is a Mootools shortcut for `Hash()` - http://mootools.net/docs/more/Types/Hash#H

Comment: For the sake of completeness :) .. `flatten` is actually a method that flattens multidimensional arrays => http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Array#Array:flatten ..tbh in your answer, it would be better to use the `append` method ;)

Comment: Yikes, every time I see a $ function in Mootools, like julio, I cringe a bit, mostly because I've become acclimatised to not seeing `$` anywhere in javascript unless PHP is involved. Although other `$...` functions have been deprecated, or replaced with other names, so I'd be wary of using this as a shortcut. (I could also be completely wrong, by the way.) The specific example I am thinking about here is `$clear`, having been deprecated in favour of `clearTimeout();`

Comment: OK so $H has actually be deprecated, it is available in more or in core w/ compatabilty the reason being is simple From mooTools Type: Hash. Hash has been deprecated. Each Hash method has a similar Object method or a Vanilla JS equivalent. This has been true since v1.3's launch

Comment: quite. Object generics have made Hash redundant, the reason it existed was to be able to get the effect of prototyping Object w/o doing so. If you want a data table, there's a Table type - else, use Object now.

Answer (score 1):

```
[note, $H(options.text).getKeys()]
```

is most likely becoming:

```
[note, ["string1", "string2"]]
```

so it returns an array. So `["whatever note is", ["Another array", "of objects"]]` needs to be flattened to:

```
["whatever note is", "Another array", "of objects"]
```